# EIGEN C++ Cannot Inverse MatrixXd

Tags: c++, matrix, inverse

I'm tried run this code below and the inverse was done allright:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
   Matrix2d A;
   A << 3, 5,
        -7, 2;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "The determinant of A is " << A.determinant() << endl;
   cout << "The inverse of A is:\n" << A.inverse() << endl;
}
```

But I'm trying inverse a MatrixXd, is this possible?

I'm trying this:

```
        MatrixXd m(2,2);
        m << 3, 5,
            -7, 2;
        cout << m.inverse() << endl;
```

This is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlbLd.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What error?  Does the program hard crash, give an unexpected answer?  Put the actual code and output in the question, your example shows a 2x2 not a 5x5.  Should work the the same way.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's a 2x2 matrix in my sample (in my real program I need inverse a 5x5, so I can't use Matrix2d). I can't compile when I use MatrixXd, you can see the error on image. Did you know a better way to inverse?

Comment: @JonasVasconcellos no, we can’t see the error in the image. You started making a [mcve], finish it up if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: No, did you tried run those examples? I can't compile the second.

Answer (score 2):

You use an `MatrixXd` the same way as a `Matrix2d` except you have to tell it how big to make the matrix.  Here is a working example with VS 2013 and Eigen 3.3.4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen\Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    Matrix2d A;
    A << 3, 5, -7, 2;
    std::cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << '\n';
    std::cout << "The determinant of A is:" << A.determinant() << '\n';
    std::cout << "The inverse of A is:\n" << A.inverse() << '\n';

    MatrixXd B(5, 5);
    B = MatrixXd::Random(5, 5);
    std::cout << "Here is the matrix B:\n" << B << '\n';
    std::cout << "The determinant of B is:" << B.determinant() << '\n';
    std::cout << "The inverse of B is:\n" << B.inverse() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

`B` can be any size you want it to be.  All `MatrixXd` is, is a typedef to `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>`.  You could also do it with

```
Matrix<double, 5, 5> C = Matrix<double, 5, 5>::Random(5, 5);
```

If you want any better explanation than this you must include the actual error you're experiencing.